# Vim code completion doesn't work after including a standard header

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete

I have to develop my project in text-mode debian linux. I'm using Vim and I installed the clang_completion plugin on it. I made `.clang_completion` file in root of my project :

```
-I.
-I/usr/include
-I/usr/include/c++/4.6
```

When I write a program like below, the completion works fine.

```
//#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  struct A
  {
    int x, y;
  };

  A a;
  a. // After putting dot, the suggestion popup appears

  return 0;
}
```

However, after removing the comment of first line, it doesn't work! How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Put a comment `/* Killer App from Outer Space */` as the first line of your file?

Comment: Run `:cope` to see the errors from Clang.

Comment: By the way, the configuration file should be `.clang_complete` and not `.clang_completion`.

Comment: Surely you should `#include <cstdio>` in C++? Could including a `C` header file confuse clang?

Comment: @Useless: No matter which header file is included, the problem occurs.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your description, I get exactly the same completion result with and without the commented line.

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way to get clang_complete to work is to use the provided cc_args.py file.

when compiling a project use clang_complete/bin/cc_args.py instead of gcc/g++

This will generate the correct .clang_complete file with all libraries and dependencies.
Provided the clang_complete source directory in your home folder.

Example Makefile:

```
CXX=$(HOME)/clang_complete/bin/cc_args.py g++

all:
    $(CXX) main.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used the `clang_complete` plugin in the past (now I just use cscope and ctags, which I consider enough).

Including external headers worked fine in my configuration, but, as the [clang complete plugin page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) specifies, the file in which to put include paths (or any other flag you may want to pass to the clang compiler), must be named `.clang_complete` and not `.clang_completion`.

Also, I used to put the options on a single line, just as I was going to pass the plain content of the `.clang_complete` file as a command line option (don't know if separating lines with `\` will work).

Hope this helps.